# Why android onLongPress always is fired after onDoubleTap?

Tags: android, double-click

I have onLongPress and onDoubleTap actions placed on the button according to this code:

```
...
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapDetector());

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    detector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapDetector());
    ... 
}

private class TapDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener { 

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
     public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {          
        // Do something          
    }
}

Button incomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.income);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

I always see onLongPress fired after onDoubleClick fired and executed. What is the reason of such counterintuitive behavior and how to avoid it?

**UPDATED**
I have changed my source code to be more specific

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
private GestureDetector detector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    detector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapDetector());    

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);                 
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("************* onTouch *************");
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });                        
}       

class TapDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {  

    @Override
     public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("************* onLongPress *************");                    
    }         

    @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("************* onDoubleTap *************");  
        Intent intent = new Intent();        
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("parameterName", "parameter");
        startActivity(intent);              
        return true;
    }             
}        
}
```

This is a log after **onDoubleTap** I clicked. You can see onLongPress at the end - I never click it.

```
I/System.out( 1106): ************* onTouch *************
I/System.out( 1106): ************* onTouch *************
I/System.out( 1106): ************* onTouch *************
I/System.out( 1106): ************* onDoubleTap *************
I/ActivityManager(   59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=my.tapdetector/.NewActivity (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   59): Displayed activity my.tapdetector/.NewActivity: 324 ms (total 324 ms)
I/System.out( 1106): ************* onLongPress *************
```

**UPDATE** I have found the solution. To avoid onLongPress firing **two** changes needs to be done:

First: detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(**true**); in onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("************* onTouch *************");
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Second: add detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(**false**); in onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)

```
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
        System.out.println("************* onDoubleTap *************");  
        Intent intent = new Intent();        
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("parameterName", "parameter");
        startActivity(intent);             
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can't repeat this, sorry. Using Log.i() on those 2 events, they're called correctly.

Comment: decent work around for what seems like a built-in race condition as described in the comments of accepted answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically this shouldn't happen

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mLastMotionX = x;
        mLastMotionY = y;
        mCurrentDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        mAlwaysInTapRegion = true;
        mInLongPress = false;

        if (mIsLongpressEnabled) {
            mHandler.removeMessages(LONG_PRESS);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(LONG_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime()
                    + tapTime + longpressTime);
        }
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(SHOW_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime() + tapTime);
```

because on the ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP event, all of the LONG_PRESS messages events are removed from the queue. So on the second tap the following code will remove the long press events.

```
 mHandler.removeMessages(LONG_PRESS);
```

> Ninja edit : hacky workaround for your problem

```
     @Override
     public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        if(MainActivity.this.hasWindowFocus())
        {
            Log.d("Touchy", "Long tap");    
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I found just now, I always get onLongPress fired after onDoubleTap **only under debugger** if breake point is set on onDoubleClick method. If I remove breake point - all is OK...

Comment: It makes sense then,  `mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime() + tapTime + longpressTime` has expired by then

Comment: It seems if I have long time processing body in the onDoubleTap method, I always will get onLongPress fired?

Comment: Huh... So, if I need long time processing inside of onDoubleTap method, what should I do to avoid onLongPress firing!?

Comment: Since you don't have access to `mHandler`, you can't do anything about it. Use Logcat for debugging instead.

Comment: I am not about debugging. I am concerned with uncontrollable runtime situation - if your method takes short time to process, you have no problem, otherwise - the problem appears.

Comment: Methods like these must process in a short time. Since they deal with UI interaction. If your method is taking longer, you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I just want to switch to other Activity on double tap. It seems to be an ordinary operation for Android. Isn't?

Comment: So you are launching an Activity? Doesn't that mean the current activity containing this code goes in a pause state? Once you start a new activity the parent activity will be inactive so you should not get any events on it.

Comment: I have updated my source code at the top and paste a log - please take a look!

Comment: Log is the same after implementing your workaround and double tap on the button. Your **Long tap** appears after long press on the button only.

Comment: Yes, now a Long press event won't come after double tap. Wasn't that what you wanted? Come to the Android chatroom if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: Ups! Yesterday I didn't understand that your trick is the solution and have found my own (added to the top)... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You see always the onLongPress fired because in your code you launch an intent before of consuming the onDoubleTap event.
You can disable onLongPress by
`public void setIsLongpressEnabled (boolean isLongpressEnabled)`
and use the onDown method for performing your action.