# Disable vibrate on Android when button held down

Tags: javascript, android

I have a webpage that repeats a button action when held down. It works great, except the phone then vibrates. Is there a way to disable vibrating?

Comment: An actual web page seen through a web browser on Android? or a web page loaded through your own WebView inside an Android wrapper? If it's the first case, it's just a user issue, the user needs to disable haptic feedback on touch and click events (if it's not already disabled). If it's the second case, yes, it can be done. You just have to tell us which case you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution wouldn't work for anyone that needs some form of haptic feedback. However, I do not, and here is the magic line that fixed it:

`webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

To disable vibrating on **longpress** use,

```
@Override
 public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {          
     AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
     audio.setRingerMode(audio.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);       
}
```

Then set it back if required.

Comment: I ended up coming up with that exact code and it did not work for me so I didn't mention it. I had put it in the `onCreate`. Was there somewhere else it should have gone?

Comment: So according to your question, you do not want it to vibrate after you have **long-pressed** the webpage right?

Comment: I'm getting a "must override or implement a supertype" error.

Comment: That's funny, the @Override should have taken care of that. Try doing super.OnLongPress(e); before disabling vibration, inside the overriden onLongPress().

Comment: `The method OnLongPress(MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Activity`

Comment: Then try implementing TapDetector class: Maybe this link will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606921/why-android-onlongpress-always-is-fired-after-ondoubletap